# how to send email from Apache server by PHP script

Tags: php, apache, email

I have installed Apache and PHP on my Windows 7 PC. I learning the PHP now. Following is my PHP script to send email.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['email']))
    {
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
        $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
        mail("padhy.surya@gmail.com","$subject","$message","From:","$email");
        echo "Thank you for using the email !!!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Mail is not set properly. Please fill the form properly";
    }
?>
```

I am using a html form to get the required parameters for sending email. Following is the error I am getting while I send the email.

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in
>   php.ini or use ini_set() in
>   C:\WebLearn\Apache-2.2\htdocs\SimpleWebsite\contact.php on line 7

Do I need to set anything to set in php.ini file or in httpd.conf? If yes how to configure it? Do I need an additional SMTP server on my PC to send email? Please suggest the necessary steps to send an email from my local PC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is saying that it's trying to deliver the email to localhost:25, and there's nothing listening there.

PHP cannot email "the Internet" directly. The message must go to a mail server program such as Postfix or Sendmail or SSMTP, which then relays it to the appropriate destination.

You must install and configure a mail server program and set PHP to use it via php.ini. I believe you also have the option of configuring PHP to use a Sendmail binary instead of SMTP delivery.

Comment: can I configure the apache server for SMTP service also? Or there is any other SMTP server I need to install for this? Is there any free SMTP server available?

Comment: @Surjya Narayana Padhi: no, Apache is an HTTP server, not an SMTP server. I mentioned three free SMTP servers in my response already.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am planning to use SendMail. Could you please let me know the steps for setting PHP to use my sendMail program?

Comment: I downloaded Free SMTP server for windows. Now its working on port 25. But when I ran my php script its shows the message as follows:           Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 Invalid recipient: padhy.surya@gmail.com

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi: you're going to have to configure the mail server to allow mail for nonlocal recipients. Out of the box, mail servers won't "relay" messages to arbitrary domains (like gmail.com). You should also make sure the mail server only listens for mail from the local host - otherwise you'd be running what's called an "open relay", which would be bad (others could use your machine to send spam).